# Will SystemExplorer trigger Kaspersky to start scanning?

Tags: anti-virus

There is a enterprise version of Kaspersky installed on my PC. The weird thing is Kaspersky sometimes unexpectedly start scanning my PC (since I can see high disk I/O read/write - 5kMB/s and page fault - 20k pages in SystemExplorer).

This only happens on my PC, so I suspect there's something triggered scan. When I check Kaspersky event log, there are hundreds of entrys look like below:

```
Process C:\Program Files\System Explorer\SystemExplorer.exe (PID 3696) tried to access Kaspersky Anti-Virus process (PID 1068), but the action has been blocked by the Self-Defense component. No action on your part is necessary.
```

SystemExplorer tries to access Kaspersky every 10 minutes. Besides that, I didn't find anything unusual. What could be the cause of the unexpectedly scanning? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based only on what you wrote I suspect SystemExplorer.exe is running periodically, in which case it's action is to be expected because it's trying to get information about what's running on your system, which includes the Kaspersky executable.

You're looking at the wrong end. Forget about Kaspersky, which is simply doeing what it's supposed to do, and start looking for whatever is causing SystemExplorer to run every 10 minutes.